# Sending text to a Java GUI with Applescript

Tags: java, applescript, javafx-2

I have a Java GUI that implements a WebView object. The WebView loads Google Docs, and the focus is set on the text editor portion of the page. I also have some Applescript that takes text input from a dialog box and sets a variable `wordString` to the result of the inputted text. I want to know if it's possible to send that text to my GUI application? I can't seem to find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up solving this problem. If your program isn't scriptable, you need to do a bit of a workaround to get some scripting done. I used the following code to send text to a Google Docs WebView:

```
tell application "System Events" to set frontmost of process "java" to true
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "java"
        keystroke newString --some text variable
    end tell
end tell
```

I got this from an example at the following site: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/applescripts-ui-scripting-mac/

I also used a program, which this site recommends for identifying application names for use within AppleScript. The program is called UIElementInspector, which can be found at http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/UIElementInspector.shtml

Hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

In your java app open a server socket. Have a look at [Writing the Server Side of a Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).
In your applescript call "nc" or "curl" to pass the wordString